# Execute script on click of a button and not on keyup

Tags: javascript, count, onclick, words

I'm trying to convert the following to be executed on a click of a button and not on keyup event. It's a text limiter. The user inputs text and I want to limit (trim down) this text to 75 characters on a click of a button.

```
<p>Type something in the textbox below: </p>
<textarea id="message" name="message" rows="4" cols="30"></textarea>
<div class="charLeft" id="countCharacter">75 characters left</div>


<script>
  function CountLeft(field, max) {
      if (field.val().length > max) 
          field.val(field.val().substring(0, max));
      else 
          jQuery(".charLeft").html((max - field.val().length) + " characters left");
  }

  jQuery("#message").keyup(

  function(event) {
      CountLeft(jQuery(this), 75); // you can increase or derease the number      depend on your need.
  }); 
</script>
```

Comment: did you tried the `keydown` event?

Comment: Where's the button? Just change the selector from `#message` to a selector for your button and change `keyup` to `click`... am I missing something? Did you grab this code from somewhere and want us to change it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a button somewhere in your html (which doesn't appear in your question), like:

```
<div id="your-button">Click Me</div>
```

Then this will achieve the effect I *think* you want.  The input will now *only* be trimmed when the user clicks `your-button`.

```
$('#your-button').click(function() {
    CountLeft($('#message'),75);
});
```

If you wanted to keep the original behavior too (which is a good idea, IMO), you could do:

```
function CheckLength(input_selector,length) {
    return function() {
        CountLeft($(input_selector),length);
    }
}

var input_selector = '#message';
var input_length = 75;
$('#your-button').click(CheckLength(input_selector,input_length));
$('#message').keyup(CheckLength(input_selector,input_length));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't want to use a button... you want to check every key type... the `keyup` event raised when you release the keyboard button, if i'm understanding right your question you want the event to be raised when you click down the button, for this, you can use the `keydown` event as described here: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

```
$('#message').keydown(function(e) {
  CountLeft(jQuery(this), 75);
});
```